# Direct upload of PDF to S3 and splitting PDF into one jpg per page in background process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, paperclip, carrierwave

So I've had some working code that uploads a pdf to s3 using paperclip ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496233/how-to-thumbnail-a-multi-page-pdf-with-paperclip)).  The code splits the PDF into a jpg/page and uploads each of them to s3 as well.

This code does not work on Heroku for larger files (I probably only need up to 10mb files) since heroku has a 30-second timeout.

I'm under the impression that simply putting the upload in a background process (delayed_paperclip gem?) will still lead to a timeout, and that I need to actually upload the file directly to s3.  I've seen I can do this with a gem [carrierwave_direct](https://github.com/dwilkie/carrierwave_direct).

So then the problem now is how to have the following code:

```
def make_manual_pages
  if valid?
    Paperclip.run('convert', "-quality #{ManualPage::QUALITY} -density #{ManualPage::DENSITY} #{manual.url} #{manual.url}%d.png")
    images = Dir.glob("#{set_ups.url}*.png").sort_by do |line|
      line.match(/(\d+)\.png$/)[1].to_i
    end

    images.each do |page_image|
      manual_pages.build(:image => File.open(page_image))
    end
    FileUtils.rm images
  end
end
```

work with carrierwave_direct.

Or maybe I'm approaching this problem wrong.. because I don't even see how I can do processing on an image if I'm directly uploading it to s3.  Maybe I need to directly upload the file, then then have heroku access the image and do the processing then?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The advantage and problem with carrierwave_direct is that your file is stored on s3 and s3 only. Carrierwave_direct have some functions to process files uploaded to s3 but all of them first download the file to your server, process it and then reupload it to s3 so all processing is done on your host.

If you need to do some processing like that of yours, carrierwave_direct won't help you with that.

One solution would be to spawn virtual machine on amazon just to process your files. Im not sure how transfer between s3 and ec2 is billed but, it won't be more then transfer back to heroku.